# Автозагрузка в termux

Tags: android, node.js, автозапуск, termux

Есть AndroidTV с полноценным андроидом 9й версии и рутовыми правами.

Настроил в termux сервер на nodejs - как поместить его в автозапуск?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого у Termux есть плагин [Termux:Boot](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux:Boot)

Comment: А без него никак?

Comment: @Qwertiy в crontab можно добавить правило `@reboot {полный путь до скрипта}`

Comment: @Qwertiy ещё можно использовать systemd

Comment: А можно поподробнее? Я так понимаю, termux - это виртуализатор некий? cron и systemd внутри термукса? Это будет работать?

Comment: @Qwertiy crontab входит в состав busybox, по идее, если termux может стартовать со стартом системы (в miui можно дать на это разрешение, как в других прошивках - не помню), то и cron будет исполнять инструкции. Сам Termux - эмулятор терминала, имеющий своё собственное linux-подобное окружение (environment). Ну, т.е. в чистом андроиде нет apt и прочего, а в Termux - есть. Systemd, кстати, нет - это я перепутал с sysctl

Comment: @Qwertiy, а почему Termux:Boot не устраивает? Он весит сущие килобайты, если проблема в объёме памяти.

Comment: Termux:Boot тупо покупать не хочется. Устройство Vontar, так что miui не в тему.

Comment: @Qwertiy покупать?Ну, может в GP оно и платное, но на FDroid - нет. https://www.f-droid.org/packages/com.termux.boot/
Да и собрать из сурцов никто не запрещает.

Comment: Ага, работает, правда были сложности с установкой после удаления гуглоплеевского варианта termux'а.

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт init.d/easer/tasker

Скорее всего придется воспользоваться chroot либо изменить переменные окружения

p.s. для установки systemd вам нужно переписывать ядро и zygote